# Data coming from an ObservableArray are displayed twice in my table

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

here is my viewModel:

### ViewModel

```
var sitesTableModel = [
{
   nameCol: "nameCol-1",
   pagesCol: "pagesCol-1",
},
{
    nameCol: "nameCol-2",
    pagesCol: "pagesCol-2",
}];

var pagesTableModel = [
{
   lastCol: "lastCol-1",
   editedCol: "editedCol-1",
},
{
    lastCol: "lastCol-2",
    editedCol: "editedCol-2",
}];


var viewModel = {
    sitesTable: ko.observableArray(sitesTableModel),
    pagesTable: ko.observableArray(pagesTableModel),
};
```

then I call a webservice in this way:

### AJAX Call

```
ajaxService = (function () {
    var ajaxGetJson = function (method, request, callback, service) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:2880/Whatever.svc/Method",
            type: "GET",
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result, statusMsg, status)
            {
                callback(result, statusMsg, status, request);
            },
            error: ServiceFailed 
        }).always(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
            });
    }
    return {
        ajaxGetJson: ajaxGetJson,
    };
})();
```

and map the result in this way:

### Mapping

```
function ModelTableSitesMapper(result, statusMsg, status, request) {

    var itemRow = [];

    //sitesTableModel
    result.forEach(function (entry) {
        itemRow.push({
            nameCol: entry.Title,
            pagesCol: entry.Pages,
        })
    });

    viewModel.sitesTable = ko.observableArray(itemRow);

};
```

And the same for the other array.

Now here is my data binding:

### Data Binding

```
    <table id="tableDocs">  
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: documentsTable" >
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: nameCol">Simon Werner Hansen</td>
            <td data-bind="text: pagesCol">swh002</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and when I get the result everything is dispoayed twice in the table.
I checked the model and there is no double data in the observableArray.
I know Iøm declaring the object as observableArray twice, and that could be the problem but I canøt find any other way to update the array than this:

```
viewModel.sitesTable = ko.observableArray(itemRow);
```

if I do this as it should be it just does not work:

```
viewModel.sitesTable(itemRow);
```

Maybe somebody could understand there reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

I was applying the binding ko.applyBinding on the **.always** function of the ajax call, but because I was calling the service twice for 2 different reasons the binding was applied **TWICE**.
That caused the duplication of data.

I just moved the binding outside the function just after I create my model.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try:

```
var viewModel = {
    sitesTable: ko.observableArray([]),
    pagesTable: ko.observableArray([]),
};
```

There's no mention of what the variables you were pre-populating the arrays with are.

Then add each item to your observable directly:

```
function ModelTableSitesMapper(result, statusMsg, status, request) {
    //sitesTableModel
    result.forEach(function (entry) {
        viewModel.sitesTable.push({
            nameCol: entry.Title,
            pagesCol: entry.Pages,
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tryed now what you said. No result is being shown on the table at all. and no error is coming back.
It looks like the observable is not "observing"

Comment: And even if I do only one of the two changes you suggest it does not work. any small change break the function...

Comment: Is there not an error in the console of the developer tools? Can you debug it? See if you can set a debug point on the viewModel.sitesTable.push line and see if it gets hit.

Comment: all the jquery part of my code works fine, I debugged it, and the values are not duplicated there. I guess it has something that happens during the databind, so it happens in knockout, somewhere...